# How would it be possible to avoid contention for a Network on an SoC (or more specifically an FPGA) from two or more nodes?

Tags: simulation, can, bus, network, soc

In a classical chip, you have a main CPU to perform general processing and it acts as the master on a some bus and other slaves (IO, Memory) usually do not send command or data autonomously. (or at least that is my basic understanding, the master knows and waits a certain amount of time for a response)

Let's say I want to implement something similar to a TPU or NPU. I want to have four processing element cores that receive work instructions from some scheduler. The scheduler can manage when to send instructions for the processing elements to perform work on, but it would have to wait for one of the processing elements to return status of when it finished.

This seems to be like a great theoretical example of using a network protocol instead of a bus to transmit command/data. However, if I were start thinking of implementing it in an FPGA for example, wouldn't the PEs have to drive the same write back to the scheduler? If that is the case, how would I know my scheduler received the correct data and not that of which another PE overwrote due to timing and the distance between the PEs to the scheduler?

I think there is a standard that indicates a PE can attempt to send out data by first reserving the network for a certain amount of time. Then if another PE also attempts to do this, the PE with either higher priority or waited longer would take it. However, I am trying to see how this would work in simulation.

In simulation, I have no info on how to "sense" another PE is attempting to reserve the network. What if I run into a simulation in which two PEs are attempting to establish a connection. Let's say I have an edge detect (where the network routing wires are weak 0 ('L' in VHDL) when idle and a PE attempting to reserve time drives its output as 1) on a PE. If two PEs attempt to reserve network time, how would I disposition that if both PEs just drove the same routing wires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If that is the case, how would I know my scheduler received the correct data and not that of which another PE overwrote due to timing and the distance between the PEs to the scheduler?

Alongside the actual data signals you have some "handshake" control signals, which tell the PE and the scheduler about status of the data transfer. Simplistically, you might have a signal from the PE which says "I want to send data" and a signal from the scheduler which says "okay, send data now". The data would remain in the PE's buffer until the scheduler says "okay, send data now".

If you only have one point-to-point connection that's a bit unnecessary. But if you want to connect *multiple* PEs to one scheduler, you don't just connect the busses in parallel (you can't, anyway). You insert an *arbiter* module which combines the 4 sets of signals into 1 set of signals. And that arbiter can tell the PEs when it's ready to receive data. If a PE wants to send data while another PE is already sending data, the arbiter won't assert the "okay, send data now" signal for that PE until the other PE has finished.

What you described is a different arbitration system (one which is more decentralized). That can work too. *You* need to wire up the signals which tell each PE whether another PE is using the bus. The simplest idea is to daisy-chain them in a priority order: PE 1 can't talk while PE 0 is talking; PE 2 can't talk while PE 0 or PE 1 is talking; etc.

Comment: some more detail on the simplistic handshaking scheme: Really you have N wires carrying the data (a word), and 1 wire which says "the data is now valid". The response wire back from the receiver says "I accepted your data into my buffer". Each clock cycle, if the receiver accepted the previous word, the sender moves to the next word in its buffer. The sender indicates valid data whenever its buffer is not empty. This doesn't cross clock domains or anything.

Answer (score 3):

> usually do not send command or data autonomously.

That's the early 1980's. In the last decades, any microcontroller, SoC, and things usually just sold as "processor" have multiple devices on-package that all have "initiative access" to a shared bus – typically, for DMA purposes.

> This seems to be like a great theoretical example of using a network protocol instead of a bus to transmit command/data.

Not really, no. This is still a bus. It's a shared thing – and you'll need *arbitration*.

Also, usually, that shared thing isn't *electrically* a connection potentially driven by multiple sources (it could be, but that's usually not how logic cells/routing works), but something where you kind of tap into one line or not. But that's a technical detail.

That can take many forms, from the scheduler regularly asking the bus interface on each of your four cores whether they are ready to send some data, to simply four (that's basically nothing) lines where a bus can signal it's ready to send data and then receive some info (either over the bus or over a dedicated control line) that it now should actually start sending data, to some fixed time slots, to some fair round robin scheduling, to simply detecting whether someone else is already using the bus and if so, waiting till they are done. You can prefix your data with a header with your own address, or rely on some known scheme for the other end to infer the origin of data.

There's really a lot of different bus architectures.

What you describe as a network doesn't sound like a network to me, just like a bus.